# Javascript - How to return a value from a function, where the inside of that function uses a .then() statement

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, async-await

EDIT: You need to have a return statement in front of Promise.all as well as a return inside the .then() as commented by Jaromanda X down below. If you're having the same problem try adding this

So in my code I have a math equations that depends on an async call to Firebase. So when I get the values back I calculate the score inside a then statement, but I can't get the function it's inside to return the calculated value. So for instance if I have something like:

```
function parentFunction(){
   let result = childFuntion()
}

function childFunction(){
    
    let query = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         let query = asyncFirebaseCall()
         resolve(query)
    }
    Promise.all([listofQueries])
    .then((res) => {
     let result = _doMathStuff(listofQueries)
     //I know this is not correct but im putting the return here
     return result
     }

}
```

how do i get the value of result inside the parent function?

Comment: `I know this is not correct but im putting the return here` actually, putting a return there is definitely required - and just add `return` in front of  `Promise.all` and you're done, `result` in the calling function will be a Promise of course

Comment: YEEEEES THIS WORKS!!! Finding out you were missing one tiny thing is the best and worst part of programming

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code at first glance:

- You're missing a top-level `return` statement inside your `childFunction` function.
- You're missing a `then` inside your `parentFunction` function.

And as Jaromanda already commented, you don't need to construct your own `Promise` objects.

So  with those two fixed, the code would look like:

```
function parentFunction(){
    childFunction().then((result) => { // 
        ...
    })
}

function childFunction(){    
    let query = asyncFirebaseCall();
    ...
    return Promise.all([listofQueries]) // 
    .then((res) => {
         let result = _doMathStuff(listofQueries)
         //I know this is not correct but im putting the return here
         return result
     }
}
```

Comment: `And as Jaromanda already commented` that was in the hastily added answer, not in the question :p but I see now what you are referring to :p

Comment: I meant the other answer not this one  :p

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function parentFunction() {
 childFunction()
 .then((result) => {
   // You can now use the 'result' calculated in childFunction here. <---=
   console.log(result);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   // Handle errors if any occurred in childFunction <---=
   console.error(error);
 });
  }

  function childFunction() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      asyncFirebaseCall()
      .then((listofQueries) => {
      let result = _doMathStuff(listofQueries);
      resolve(result);
      })
     .catch((error) => {
    reject(error); // errors <---=
  });
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The main issue is that you're trying to return a value from an asynchronous operation as if it was synchronous. Instead, you should return a promise from childFunction and handle it in parentFunction.

My suggested code:

```
function parentFunction(){
   childFunction()
   .then(result => {
       console.log(result);
       // now you have the result inside the parentFunction
       // do whatever you want with it
   })
   .catch(error => {
       console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
   });
}

function childFunction(){
    // if asyncFirebaseCall() itself returns a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let query = asyncFirebaseCall();
        // if there are multiple queries, push them all into an array and then use Promise.all
        Promise.all([query])
        .then(responses => {
            let result = _doMathStuff(responses);
            resolve(result);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

A few points:

asyncFirebaseCall() should return a promise.

I used Promise.all() even if there's one promise for demonstration purposes. If you have multiple promises, you can add them in the array.

The promise inside childFunction is resolved with the result from the _doMathStuff function.

In the parentFunction, you call childFunction and handle its returned promise.

By doing this, you are correctly handling the asynchronous nature of your operations and can get the result of your calculations in the parentFunction when it's ready.

Comment: no need to construct a new Promise, since Promise.all returns a Promise already - so, really,all you need is `return Promise.all(... rest of OP's code )`